# Parsing error Unity 3D

Tags: parsing, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I keep on getting this error code (UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end.), and I really just dont get why. Please help, what am I overlooking:

```
#pragma strict

private var vibrateTimer : float = 0.0;
function Update()
{
    if (action);
    {
        vibrate on();
            vibrateTimer = 0.25;
    }

    if (vibrateTimer > 0.0);
    {
        vibrateTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (vibrateTimer <= 0.0);
        {
            vibrate off();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not have a `;` on the same line as your `if ()` statements.

Comment: You can't have spaces in your function name (@ `vibrate on()`).  Especially if that function doesn't even exist. What exactly are you trying to do? It seems to me that you have just started to learn how to code. You're mixing several languages (Javascript, C#, and ?), please make sure you get familiar with thte language first. And also, please don't just edit your original sourceode without further notice, atleast write down what you've changed seperatly. That way, nobody can make sense of the given answers.

Answer (score 1):

Is this Javascript or C# or UnityScript? The `using UnityEngine;` says C#, the `function` says Javascript, the `vibrate on` says neither. Please clarify.

Starting from

```
private var vibrateTimer : float = 0.0 ();
{
 //....
}
```

why are you wrapping the whole code in `{ }`? 
 Also,

```
vibrate on
vibrateTimer = 0.25f;
```

(the first line) is not valid C# code. Also the variable declaratoin

```
private var vibrateTimer : float = 0.0 ();
```

with the `()` at the end seems wrong to me. But the wrapping the whole code in `{}` might be your first error source.